How do I make a fast-rendering image for my project? I am using free Vercel hosting
I had deployed my project on Vercel under the name design2code. Design2Code is a platform where developers can share their projects with other developers. But when I add a new project to my website, it takes too much time to render an image, while on a local host it is done quickly.
Add images fast in the create template of projects.
Project Url: https://www.designtocode.me/
Github Url: https://github.com/Dheerajjha451/Design2Code

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can implement these methods:

Use a CDN like cloudinary to host and render the images
Convert the images to WebP format as they are lightweight and load faster


I am already using cloudinary free version.

It is resolved, thanks.
